# Is there a language-agnostic way to add a pause in VoiceOver readout?

Tags: swiftui, accessibility, voiceover

I have a SwiftUI view that needs a custom accessibility label applied to it. That label reads a couple of strings at once, and I would like to have VoiceOver pause between them.

I'm currently placing a comma between the strings in the `accessibilityLabel(_:)` modifier to get VoiceOver to pause between them. However, a colleague mentioned that this may not behave the same in other languages.

Is there a way to explicitly tell VoiceOver to pause in an accessibility label that doesn't have localization risks?

```swift
struct ExampleView: View {

  private let string1 = "Example string #1"
  private let string2 = "Example string #2"

  var body: some View {
    Color.red
      .accessibilityLabel("\(string1), \(string2)")
  }
}
```

Comment: Any punctuation will cause VoiceOver to pause briefly as it's speaking. You can use a comma, period, semicolon, etc.  However, keep in mind that a Braille user might be accessing your app and **not** using VoiceOver. So whatever label you have, use the proper grammatical punctuation to cause the pause so that it'll **read** correctly with Braille. Don't just toss in a semicolon, for example, just to cause the pause if a semicolon isn't the right grammatical punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to insert commas or whatevers manually between several strings.
Instead, the string used as label should be in your translation system, so that the correct punctuation or separator is properly used in all languages in which your app is translated.

I don't know swift, but basically, don't do that:

```
label = one + ", " + two + ", " + three;
```

Which will be incorrect in languags not using commas,
but prefer something like:

```
label = format(translate("some.label"), one, two, three)
```

Where "some.label" is a key inside a translation file, mapping to something like "{}, {}, {}" in english, but maybe "{}; {}; {}" in another language.